# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date for String

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have a date in String format, which I parse using SimpleDateFormat, but to my surprise I keep getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Error.

I thought I was getting the pattern wrong, but I looked closely & i don't think so, I'm wondering what my issue might be:

I Keep getting

```
E/FormatFormDate: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-02-25T22:43:23.213Z"
```

This is my code below:

```
var clean = "2019-02-25T22:43:23.213Z"

val inputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
val outputFormatTime = "HH:mm"
val DATE_TIME_ONLY = SimpleDateFormat(outputFormatTime, Locale.getDefault())
if (clean != "") {
    try {
        val parseDate = SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.getDefault()).parse(clean)
        clean = DATE_TIME_ONLY.format(parseDate)
        Log.d("TAG", clean)

    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        Log.e("FormatFormDate", Log.getStackTraceString(e))
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Date String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480189/parse-date-string-in-java)

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Yes @OleV.V. I hardly ever spotted my problem because I believed my pattern was correct, so even though I saw that answer. I thought it wasn't for me. Thanks for the Jake Wharton link, Let me check it out & try to update my answer if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my Issue:

My pattern was wrong, I was meant to do this:

```
val inputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

But Instead I was doing this:

```
val inputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Notice the single quotes with 'Z'

Comment: Wrong answer. `Z` is a UTC offset of zero and must be parsed as such, or you get the wrong time (on the vast majority of Java installations).